# How do I get the city output to append itself into initials and then print it?

Tags: python, if-statement, append

**Ensure the code was created and run in Task 1 to import cities.txt

1. Create and run code to re-open cities.txt as cities_file
2. read() cities_file into a variable called cities
3. Iterate through the characters in cities a. Test if .isupper(), if True append the character to a string variable: initials c. Else if (elif) character is "\n", if True append the "\n" to initials**
4. Print initials

cities_file = open('cities.txt', 'r')

cities = cities_file.read()

initials = " "

for city in cities:

if city.isupper() == True:

```
city += initials
```

elif city == "\n":

```
city += initials
```

print(initials)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take off the "== True" part-That is the only issue

```
initials = ""
cities_file = open("cities.txt", "r")
cities = cities_file.read()
for c in cities:
    if c.isupper():
initials += c
    elif c == "\n":
initials += c
print(initials)
```